# NodeJS. Передача в https/http.createServer заранее определенной функции обработчика

Tags: javascript, node.js

В проекте есть необходимость в зависимости от конфигурационного файла создать несколько веб серверов на разных портах. Сервера выполняют одну и ту же роботу, получить пакет и по веб сокету отправить на указанных в конфе урл (для каждого сервера свой).
Так как сервера могут быть либо http либо https

```
// Получаем список серверов с параметрами
var servers = config.get('servers');

// Проходим по списку и запускаем сервера
for (var server in servers) {
    if (servers.hasOwnProperty(server)) {
        new ProxyServer(server, servers[server]).run();
    }
}
```

Класс `ProxyServer`:

```
var ProxyServer = function (serverName, serverParams) {
    this.type = serverParams.type;
    // инициализация остальных свойств
};

ProxyServer.prototype.run = function () {
    if (this.type === 'https')
        this.createHttpsServer();
    else
        this.createHttpServer();
};

ProxyServer.prototype.createHttpsServer = function () {
    var me = this;
    https.createServer({
        key: fs.readFileSync(config.get('app.SSLCertificateKeyFile')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(config.get('app.SSLCertificateFile'))
    }, function (req, res) {
        me.packageProcessing(req, res);
    }).listen(me.port);
};

ProxyServer.prototype.createHttpServer = function () {
    var me = this;
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        me.packageProcessing(req, res);
    }).listen(me.port);
};

ProxyServer.prototype.packageProcessing = function (req, res) {
    // логика обработки входящих пакетов
};
```

Вопрос в следующем, почему нельзя функцию `packageProcessing(req, res)` поместить как аргумент в `createServer` вместо анонимной функции упростив синтаксис с такого

```
ProxyServer.prototype.createHttpServer = function () {
    var me = this;
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        me.packageProcessing(req, res);
    }).listen(me.port);
};
```

до такого вида

```
ProxyServer.prototype.createHttpServer = function () {
    http.createServer(packageProcessing(req, res)).listen(me.port);
};
```

Comment: Потому что контекст вызова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом вашем примере, вы вызываете `packageProcessing` используя `this` (через ссылку в `me`) в качестве *контекста вызова*.

Во втором случае вы вызываете *некую функцию* `packageProcessing` (с неопределенными на момент выполнения аргументами) и передаете *результат ее выполнения* в `http.createServer`. Это не правильно.

В вашем случае стоит использовать метод [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) для создания функции, привязанной к контексту выполнения. После этого, созданную функцию вы можете смело передать в `createServer`. Например так:

```
ProxyServer.prototype.createHttpServer = function () {
    http.createServer(this.packageProcessing.bind(this)).listen(this.port);
};
```